# Send object to UIViewController from UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an object that is sent from my main VC to my MasterTabViewController(UITabBarController) in the viewDidLoad I NSLog the object and it shows the object, good. Now I need that object to go to the first tab UIViewController. I tried multiple times and cannot get it to go. I am new so forgive my ignorance,

I send the object from my main vc to my MasterTabViewController via segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showLogin"])
    {
        MasterTabViewController *preview = segue.destinationViewController;
        preview.communityTapped = self.tempCommunity;

    }



}
```

^This works fine!^ self.tempCommunity is an instance community object.

MasterTabViewController.h

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    FirstTabViewController *firstvc;
    firstvc.communityTapped = self.communityTapped;
    NSLog(@"%@ !!!!!!!!! ",self.communityTapped.commDescription);

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

FirstTabViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *descriptionLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Community *communityTapped;
```

FirstTabViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.descriptionLabel.text = self.communityTapped.commDescription;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated as I have tried and failed many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set up IBOutlets to a tab bar controllers view controllers (and I see from your project that you never hooked them up). In your viewDidLoad for the tab bar controller, you can get a reference to any of its view controllers with the `viewControllers` property. So do something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.firstvc = self.viewControllers[0];
    self.firstvc.communityTapped = self.communityTapped;
    NSLog(@"%@ !!!!!!!!! ",self.communityTapped.commDescription);
}
```

Comment: And if I want to call the second tab do I just change the 0 to 1?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the `viewDidLoad` of your `MasterTabViewController.h`. You're creating the variable `firstvc`, but you're not setting the value to anything. So when you set the value of `communityTapped` in the next line, you're trying to set the value of `communityTapped` on nothing.

### Option 1

If you've set up the tab in interface builder, you need to create an `IBOutlet` in your `MasterTabViewController.h` and connect it to your view controller. Something like the following:

`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet FirstTabViewController *firstvc;`

Then to set the value of the `communityTapped`, property, you would use something like this:

`self.firstvc.communityTapped = self.communityTapped`

### Option 2

The other option would be to create the tab pragmatically, and add it to the view. I'm not sure quite what your setup is, but I imagine it would be something like this:

`FirstTabViewController *firstvc = [[FirstTabViewController alloc] init];
firstvc.communityTapped = self.communityTapped;
NSArray *viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstvc, nil];
[self.navigationController.tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO];`

Comment: It is still null see whole project here:

http://steveedwin.com/Local%20Communiti.es.zip